# Changing Delphi 10 auto generated files (identcache, dof, cfg...)

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Is there a way to change the path that those files are generated? By default it's generated in the same folder as the `.dproj` file.

I would like to change:

- .cfg
- .dof
- .identcache
- .res
- .stat
- .dproj.local
- and if possible, but a little different, the unit backup files (~ddp, ~dfm and ~pas)

Currently using Delphi 10.3 Rio

Comment: Not as far as I know. The compiler looks for them in the project folder, so the IDE puts them there.

Comment: That's a bummer. All of those files could be hidden for a clearer workspace, since we don't directly change them

Comment: @RodolfoDonãHosp: would be a nice Feature Request in Quality Portal. It would indeed be nice to get rid of these files in the project folder.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Exactly, i get the purpose of them, but there's no need to mix them with files that you change all the time

Comment: If you get tangled by them in a git/svn repository, maybe a .gitignore file or svn:ignore property is a better idea.

Comment: @Marcodor: of course you can keep them out of a remote repository, but  they still clutter the project directory. Would be nice if we could keep them out of sight.

Comment: We already use svn's ignore list, but locally, the files all mixed up with actually useful files (like the .dpr) is a pain

Comment: Just hide the files

Comment: as mentioned before ... we just use a .gitignore or .svnignore and that way the files don't get into version control at least. Before that I used the Clean Directories tool form GExperts to get rid of that stuff,